# In a step for proving $\sum\limits_{cyc}{abc}\le5$ when $a + b + c + d + e = 5$.

Tags: inequality, summation, solution-verification

I had the following problem in my book-
$$
abc + bcd + cde + dea + eab \le5
$$
which is to be proved for non - negative real numbers satisfying $a + b + c + d + e = 5$.

Suppose $min(a,b,c,d,e) = e$,
My question is: Is this even possible?
Say on an occasion, $b$ is the least,
It's obvious as the sum is cyclic not symmetric,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f(a,e,c,d,b)
&= aec + ecd + cdb + dba + eab\\
&= abd + abe + ace + bcd + cde\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Hence,
$$
f(a,b,c,d,e) \neq f(a,e,c,d,b)
$$
This was the first step to the solution to this problem, in my textbook.
But in my opinion, this is wrong.
May someone explain me where I went wrong, if I did.
Thanks!

Comment: The sum in your title doesn't involve $d$ or $e$... why?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork $\sum_{cyc}{abc} = abc + bcd + cde + dea + eab$. I didn't mention it there because it is already known to involve $5$ variables (as $a + b + c + d + e = 5$).

Comment: I would definitely argue the title is written correctly using cyclic notation.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon $f(a,b,c,d,e)\neq f(a,e,c,d,b)$ is correct. I have tried that the statement of the first line of proof of the solution is incorrect. It said: Suppose $min(a,b,c,d,e) = e$.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in *assuming* that $e$ is the smallest (so it is not always true, but we imagine it is and proceed), but it seems you are on to something. What happens in the proof after that?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon If any of the variables except $e$ is the smallest, then the inequality is not the same, that is what I have shown in my post.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the inequality is not the same. So those cases will have to be handled. I wanted to know the rest of the book proof to see how that is handled : that is, if the book is handling the case "$a,b,c$ or $d$ is the smallest of the five" the way you are saying, it is definitely wrong.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Definitely not. It just assumes that $e$ is minimal and proves the inequality.

Comment: You are correct : one cannot assume **WLOG** that $e$ is minimal. One is *losing generality* if $e$ is minimal, as you point out.  So the book must be doing the other cases separately, and if not then there's something off. If there is still a confusion, and you feel the book is not wrong, then direct me to the book so I can read the proof and rephrase it for you. Every good book will still have some unclear statements.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I am adding the entire proof to the question...

Comment: Thank you so much for this discussion, +1 to your question.

Comment: The proof is given by @nguyenhuyen_ag in one answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the proof in book is

> Note $$abc + bcd + cde + dea + eab = e(c+a)(b+d)+bc(a+d-e). \quad (*)$$
> Suppose $e = \min (a,b,c,d,e)$ and using the AM-GM inequality,
> we have $$e(c+a)(b+d)+bc(a+d-e) \leqslant\frac{e(c+a+b+d)^2}{4}+\frac{(b+c+a+d-e)^3}{27} $$
> $$=\frac{e(5-e)^2}{4}+\frac{(5-2e)^2}{27}.$$ We need to prove
> $$\frac{e(5-e)^2}{4}+\frac{(5-2e)^2}{27} \leqslant 5,$$  equivalent to
> $$(e+8)(e-1)^2 \geqslant 0.$$ Done.

**Note.** Now, what happened if $b$ is the least? The key is identity $(*).$

Indeed, if $b = \min (a,b,c,d,e)$ we write $(*)$ as
$$abc + bcd + cde + dea + eab = b(c+e)(a+d)+de(c+a-b).$$
$$ \leqslant \frac{b(c+e+a+d)^2}{4}+\frac{(d+e+c+a-b)^2}{27}.$$
$$ = \frac{b(5-b)^2}{4}+\frac{(5-2b)^2}{27}.$$
If $c = \min (a,b,c,d,e)?$ We write $(*)$ as
$$abc + bcd + cde + dea + eab=c(b+e)(a+d)+ae(b+d-c).$$
$$\leqslant  \frac{c(5-c)^2}{4}+\frac{(5-2c)^2}{27}.$$
Similar to $c, d,a$ is the least, and using the AM-GM inequality as above.

**Conclude.** Without loss of generality we can suppose $e = \min(a,b,c,d,e).$

Comment: Yes, this is the proof in my book!

Comment: Can you please insert the whole proof if $b$ was the least?

Comment: @BookOfFlames Now I get it : the proof was done for $e$ the smallest. If $b$ is the smallest, then $e \to b$ is like a cyclic shift of $2$ indices.  So in the proof for $e$ being the smallest, just literally change $e \to b, a \to c,b \to d,c \to e, d \to a$ in each of the statements, and you get the proof if $b$ is the smallest! Similarly if $c$ is the smallest, $e \to c$ is a cyclic shift of $3$, so shift all variables in the statements by $3$

Comment: @TeresaLisbon If that is calculus, I don't understand as I don't know much of it.

Comment: @BookOfFlames See update post.

Comment: @nguyenhuyen_ag Yes, thank you! (accepted)

Comment: The equivalence doesn't use calculus, it uses just LCMs , polynomial factorization and so on. There is an error in the power of $5-2e$ which I have asked to be corrected.

Comment: @nguyenhuyen_ag Correction : the $5-2e$ has $3$ as exponent everywhere, not $2$.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Then too I am not familiar, if $e\rightarrow b $ and $b\rightarrow d$ then $e\rightarrow d$?

Comment: @BookOfFlames I will try to explain. See, if $e$ is the smallest then we had some argument which worked, right? Now, what happens if $b$ is the smallest? The identity $*$, which we used for $e$, is *cyclically invariant* : if we "cycle" or "shift" permute $a,b,c,d,e$ ,then we get another way of expressing the LHS. For example, the identity used to prove the $b$ smallest situation, is obtained from the $e$ situation by changing every $e$ to $b$, every $a$ to $c$, every $b $ to $d$, every $c$ to $e$ and every $d$ to $a$. Continued...

Comment: @BookOfFlames Once we do that, we observe that the same inequality which we had to prove for $e$, comes out except that $e$ is replaced by $b$. So, the *entire proof for $b$ smallest is a "cyclical" permutation of the entire proof for $e$ smallest*. For this reason, it is *possible* (but I would still disagree) to say "WLOG" let $e$ be the smallest, because one can *reproduce* the proof for $b$ smallest, from the proof for $e$ smallest, by cycling the indices. (Note : by $e\to b$, I meant : change every $e$ to a $b$ in the proof, and so on.).

Comment: @TeresaLisbonYes I saw that in the above answer. But it is difficult to come up with such proof, and even more tough to notice the WLOG!

Answer (score 2):

While you already have a good answer which shows why it doesn't matter in the specific problem, please note that this is in fact general.

It is true that in **ANY** cyclic case, we may WLOG take any of the variables to be the minimum (*or maximum*).  This is because you can cycle through $(a, b, c, d, e)  \rightarrow (b, c, d, e, a) \rightarrow (c, d, e, a, b)  \rightarrow (d, e, a, b, c) \rightarrow (e, a, b, c, d)...$ to get the minimum (*or maximum*) to occupy the first position or the last position, or any of the positions you desire.

In your particular e.g. what matters is that $f(c, d, e, a, b) = f(a, b, c, d, e)$, so it doesn't matter if $b$ is the smallest instead of $e$.

In fact you can even say WLOG things like let $a, b, c$ be s.t. $b \geqslant \max(a, c)$. Again the logic is the same, in a (cyclic) sequence, you will somewhere always find one number at least as high as its neighbours, and then you can cyclically push that triplet to the front. Or things like WLOG let $b-a$ be the highest among consecutive differences.  If that helps solve the particular inequality in question, great!

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail how in **any** cyclic sum WLOG we can assume a variable to be minimal or maximal?

Comment: That's what is done above. Which line is troublesome to you?

Comment: I have learnt that symmetric sum we can assume WLOG any variable is minimal. But how does it occur in cyclic sum?

Comment: In a symmetric sum you can do much more. You can assume $a,b,c,d,e$ are in order for e.g. - say ascending.